Can the plasma jet emitted from a supermassive black hole form a naturally-occurring Tipler cylinder?
I want to preface the question with 'obviously, it's not a real Tipler cylinder, being finite in some -t direction before the black hole formed.'
A Tipler cylinder is defined as some rotating mass of infinite length in both the time and space axes, around which one can orbit at some distance to achieve time travel into the past.
Meanwhile, sufficiently massive black holes can emit ionized mass in a uniform (?) direction that travels at a high enough speed to achieve relativistic effects. Most (all?) black holes found in nature rotate, which means this beam of mass should technically be 'rotating' as well if emitted parallel to the axis of rotation.
So, my questions are - could those very same jets, if of sufficient size, become naturally-occurring Tipler cylinders? If not, why not? How large (or massive?) would they have to be in order for this to happen? How large would the black hole have to be?
The goal, here, is to give a character a reasonable method of time-travel to approximately 2 million years into their past (long before they were ever born) without requiring them to approach relativistic speeds themselves. I'd like to describe this using as 'correct' physics as possible - hence the Tipler cylinder, which (as far as I know) has never been disproven, only constrained by the weak-energy condition and its own dimensional limitations.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but black holes don't emit mass, they radiate it away as hawking radiation, right? But more to the point, are you asking a science question better suited for [astronomy.se]? Or are you looking for help using some science concepts to rationalize a worldbuilding rule (in which case, whether or not the idea can really work is irrelevant).

I want to say I’ve seen a proposal like this that involved two contra-rotating supermassive black holes orbiting each other, anchoring the cylinder on each end. Sorry I don’t have the reference.

@JBH Black holes with large accretion disks can end up throwing a small fraction of the inspiraling matter out perpendicular to the disk at relativistic speed - most of the mass is absorbed and then later released as Hawking radiation, though, yes.

I've seen claims that appropriate flares on the ends of a finite massive cylinder could produce a region near the center of the cylinder's length that would act as a Tipler cylinder.  The flared ends, in effect, reproduce the gravitational effects of infinite length.  Note that this thing would still mass much more than most stars and would need to be at least light-hours (if not light-weeks) long...

Strictly speaking, a Tipler cylinder needs to be infinite in length in order to work (you know that of course), and I don't think I don't think anything similar has ever been proposed. Usually the funky time shenanigans are proposed to happen inside the black hole haha. But I wouldn't let this stop you because it's a very cool idea, and there's maybe a mechanism for it. If you shut your physics textbook and dream a little.
Black holes have extreme space-time curvature which contributes to something called squeezed states of vacuum. I'm not an expert, but as I understand it, oscillator states of the vacuum are limited by curvature in an effect similar to the Casimir effect. The result is that the black hole is surrounded by a region of negative energy density which is responsible for Hawking radiation.
You could handwave and say somehow some of this negative energy is extracted from the blackhole and woven into the astrophysical jets, creating the desired effect.

Somehow, I'd completely forgotten about the local negative energy density required for a finite Tipler cylinder. Maybe an Alcubierre drive could get involved as an alternative? The character has to get to the plasma jet somehow, after all. I think this would produce a 'local' finite-Tipler-cylinder-region on an otherwise non-Tipler plasma jet, but I'm not sure.

@elementcollector1 Any unlimited system of FTL (meaning not limited by special universal frames of reference) can be used at will to travel backwards in time. Wormholes, Alcubierre drive, you name it. Skip the whole issue of causality, though. They all require some form of null energy condition violating properties. There's no science to speak of on finite Tipler cylinders afaik, so it's up to you on how you want to explain it. Personally, I think the initial concept is interesting as a world/story element.

Absolutly not.
Tipler Cylinders rely on several impossible assumptions to work. Such as being infinitely long. Even if you ignore that, Astrophysical jets produced by Kerr black holes, or any other massive rotating object for that matter, do not satisfy a core assumption of the Tipler Cylinder. That their frame dragging is constant along the cylinder length. The Polar region´s of a Kerr black hole already have the weakest Frame dragging, and it decreases in strength drastically as you move away. While part of an Astrophysical Jets mechanics are driven by Frame dragging, its really not relevant. Jets are dominated by Magnetohydrodynamics and just not very massive. Plus the little mass they do have rapidly spreads out / diffuses.

If one black hole is not enough, how about two?
I want to disclaim that I will be making unverifiable assumptions in my argument, but I believe the core is solid.
Imagine two rotating black holes moving towards each other. One has a very strong relativistic jet. Now these are not merging black holes, nor are they in a collision course. However, they will pass by each other at a relatively short distance. The end result will be equivalent to a grav assist fly by. Both black holes will carry on their merry way but with their directions altered by each other's gravity.
Now, imagine that these two black holes also share the same rotation plane. Meaning their axes of rotation are parallel. Additionally, they are rotating in the same direction.
As they pass by, for some small amount of time, they will share the exact same axis and the relativistic jet from one black hole will be pointed exactly at the other.
Here, we can make some interesting assumptions about the brief event and we could exploit some definitions of singularities to create your infinite Tipler cylinder.
The jet can now be confined and prevented from dissipating as it will be accelerated towards the other black hole by its gravity. It is possible to assume that this jet will be moving very fast and rotating very rapidly as it falls into the adjacent black hole.
Additionally, and this is where we tip into some fiction, you could argue that the axis between the two black holes is infinite. The infinite curvature of spacetime at the singularity would provide the asymptotic component necessary to satisfy the Tipler solution to the general relativity equations.
This would be an exceedingly rare event (if not impossible), so when you character is thrown back in time, he may be there for good.

Time travel with a tipler cylinder requires flying around the cylinder repeatedly, where you go back in time gradually with each orbit. You cannot go back to a time before the existence of the cylinder, so if this structure exists only for a brief moment, it is not useable that way.

Thats true. We would need a period of stability so that the traveler would have enough time to orbit the cylinder. It could also explain how they escaped the event. They traveled back far enough to before the cylinder was formed.

With a lot of handwaving, maybe
As mentioned, Hawking proved that a finite-length Tipler cylinder would need negative mass somewhere. But that is a fairly easy hurdle - the math needed to prove that is very esoteric and should be simple to explain away - a mistake in the assumptions, some new effect near event horizons, an exotic particle produced in the stream  ...
However, the bigger problem: A Tipler cylinder needs a giant rotating mass, dragging spacetime itself with it.
To provide a Tipler-like effect, the plasma jet would need to rotate around its own axis at near lightspeed.
However, these jets are just a stream of loose particles, there is nothing pulling them towards the axis of the jet, so they cannot rotate around that axis.
If the particles had any sideways motion, they would just fly apart in a wide cone instead of a tight jet.
So you cannot have proper rotation in a plasma jet. However, the individual particles can have spin, which is kind of similar. If each particle in the stream spun around its own axis and all particles had their spin aligned, you might be able to get enough frame-dragging for a closed time-like path to form around the jet? (probably not, but perhaps plausible enough for a story)
How do you get all particles' spin aligned? A charged particle with spin is a tiny magnet. A black hole that is charged and spinning is a giant magnet.
So, take a black hole that has a massive electric charge, as well as a massive spin: it will act as a giant magnet, aligning all the spins of the escaping particles.
Unfortunately, I believe various particles and their anti-particles would spin in opposite directions when aligned this way, cancelling each other out.
But, due to its massive electric charge, mainly particles with the opposite charge would be able to escape the black hole, so you could use that to explain how the whole jet has uniform spin.
Or perhaps the black hole is in a region of space that somehow got a giant surplus of e.g. protons, so the jet contains mainly protons, with all their spins aligned.
